# backtrace a tree without mutable members

Tags: java, scala, oop, tree, functional-programming

I am trying to make a recursive tree such that `parent` has reference to `child` and `child` has reference to `parent`. The thing I am trying to do is to backtrace the tree from a `child` whitout mutable members. It is hard because giving the child a reference to the `parent` in the constructor requireds the `parent` instance to be already created.

I only could think of two ways and both are not so good. The first way is the fallowing

1. create child instance with function "setParent()" which only works once with the help of a private boolean variable.
2. create parent and pass the child instance.
3. the parent will pass itself to "setParent()".

After that, child has reference to parent and setParent() cannot be used.

The second way is to create `parent` and `child` completly separate but hold them in some sort of data structure which can search for `parent` of some child and the otherway arround.

If there is a better way please teach me. I work mainly in java but the question is general.

Comment: Normally you create a tree from top to bottom or combine two sub-trees to get a new tree, etc. So when appending a new child or combining two sub-trees every node knows who is its parent. By the way can you post your code, it will be much easier to get the context that way.

Comment: [This blog post](http://akikhtenko.github.io/blog/2013/12/15/immutable-double-linked-tree-construction-in-scala/) seems promising and is exactly what you want.

Comment: By the way be aware of performance concerns with this approach. Depending on your actual requirement, better solutions may exist.

Comment: I think that if you really want an immutable data structure, you should try really hard to avoid the reference to the parent. One way to do this would be to pass the parent explicitly in traversal methods. Note that it is perfectly viable to have a reference to the parent, but that means that you will have to make a copy of the **entire tree** every time you do a modification. If you avoid the parent reference, you can have structural sharing, which is a prerequisite for all efficient functional data structures.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this, but I'd probably give the parent a `createChild` method that creates a new node, passing itself as the parent, and adds this child to itself before returning it. You imply in the question that having a preexisting parent is difficult for some reason, but if you're making a tree, you ought to know whose parents are whose. If you don't, a tree might not be the data structure you're looking for.

I'd probably structure it such that your `Element` constructor may take another `Element`. If so, it sets a private variable (`parent`) to that other `Element`. If it's created without a parent element passed in, it will never have a parent. So the class might look something like this (omitting accessors and any other stuff obviously):

```
public class Element {

    private Element parent;
    private ArrayList<Element> children;

    // Constructor for a node with NO parent
    public Element() {
        this(null);
    }

    // Constructor for a node WITH a parent
    public Element(Element parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.children = new ArrayList<Element>();
    }

    // Method to create a child element.
    public Element createChild() {
        Element ch = new Element(this);
        this.children.add(ch);
        return ch;
    }
}
```

---

If your problem is that you're trying to build a "tree" by tracing from a child up to some ancestor, then I encourage you to notice that that's actually a list, not a tree. You can just make the list from bottom to top and then build the tree from top to bottom by starting at the end of the list.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I think the class Element is mutable which is the exact problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: @user98456 It's only mutable if you allow it to be mutable. In this particular case, the existence of the `createChild` method does make an element mutable (via adding new children) but if you have specific immutability requirements, just make members private as needed to enforce immutability. But I'd question the immutability requirement first.